# Strange colored beams. Does anyone know the plugin or which option created?

Tags: visual-studio, plugins

Screenshot of the Problem:

[image: Screenshot of the Problem]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those red blocks are showing whitespace (spaces or tabs) that is present at the end of a line, aka "trailing whitespace".  Google shows several extensions that will do that kind of highlighting.  This looks like it might be the "Trailing Whitespace Visualizer" extension, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.TrailingWhitespaceVisualizer

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may have unintentionally selected ["Highlight Code Coverage"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKCfh.png) To turn it off, open the Code Coverage Results window and click the Code Coverage Coloring button again to toggle it off.

- To toggle displaying which lines have been run, choose this - [https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Hl8.png]